# Is Parallelism Reflexive?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

The book I'm reading to teach myself Discrete Maths(Schaumm's Outlines of Theory and Problems of Discrete Mathematics), says that parallelism '||' is not reflexive. That struck me as odd, because I assumed it was.

(An explanation without vector geometry):
Two lines are paralell if they have equal gradients. I.e: $M_1 = M_2$.

Now for any given line $A$ with gradient $M_1$, $M_1 = M_1$.

Contrast this with perpendicularity Where $M_1\cdot M_2 = -1$. For a line to be perpendicular to itself, $M_1^2 = -1$. $M_1 = \sqrt{-1}$

$M_1 \not\in R$
$\therefore$ a line is not perpendicular to itself.

So is paralellism reflexive?

Comment: See [parallelism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_(geometry)#Reflexive_variant) : " In Euclidean geometry a line is **not** considered to be parallel to itself" (see sources).

Comment: The issue may be (my supposition) that **if** we define *parallelism* with a line and a point "external" to that line, than we cannot say that a line is parallel to itself... See [Euclid I.31](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookI/propI31.html) for the construction of parallel lines.

Comment: What's Euclid's definition.

Comment: @TobiAlafin: Euclid's definition I 23 is *"Parallel straight lines are straight lines which, being in the same plane and being produced indefinitely in both directions, do not meet one another in either direction."*

Answer (score 2):

It may depend on your definition of *parallel*.

If it means "lies in the same plane but with no coincident points" then no line is parallel to itself, given each point is coincident with itself

Comment: How about _lie in the same plane, but do not have a singleton as intersection."_ or the mathematically equivalent _"lie in the same plane, but do not have exactly one intersection point"_

Comment: @TobiAlafin A different definition may produce a different result.

Answer (score 2):

As @Mauro says in the comments, it depends on the definition of **parallel**. The question that arises is: *Can a line be parallel to itself?*

---

This appears to be a matter of convention. Since the advantage of a positive answer far outweighs the alternative, we can take the definition of parallel lines to be lines which do not have exactly one point in common.

Comment: But by your definition, a line is parallel to itself.